# Why is a calzone called calzone?

Tags: etymology, latin, italian

I was just researching its etymology and turns out that it comes from *calceus* the Latin for shoe! How did Latin for *shoe* end up as the Italian (and subsequently, English) for a snack? They seem so unrelated!

Here's what [Merriem Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calzone) says about its etymology:

> **Origin of CALZONE**
>
> Italian, from calzone (singular of calzoni pants), augmentative of
>   calza stocking, from Medieval Latin calcea, from Latin calceus shoe,
>   from calc-, calx heel First Known Use: 1947

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if etymology of Italian cuisine is on-topic here. But maybe the snack looks like a shoe?

Comment: The word has been adopted well enough in English to ensure the question is on-topic. All major dictionaries should attest this. And to me, the snack looks rather like a half moon than a shoe.

Comment: Then I am quite sure that to you, a _croissant_ probably does _not_ look like a moon (since it doesn't look much like a calzone) and yet, the _croissant_ was named after the moon. Whether a calzone looks like a shoe may largely depend on your pizza-baker, as well as your shoe-maker. Maybe if both are Italian, they may look alike. Anyway, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calzone) indicates that it's not from shoe, but the derived word meaning _trouser-leg_. Maybe it looks more like a trouser-leg to you?

Comment: It doesn't matter what it looks like to me personally. Looking at the picture, nobody can relate them with trousers or shoes. That's why I am trying to understand how the transition happened. Anyways, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: No, there is no relation between *calzone* and *shoe*.

Comment: @oerkelens ElberichSchneider The word does originate from the Latin for shoe. See the reference added to the question.

Comment: But the connection between filling a stocking or a trouser leg, and folding a pasta-sheet so it can be filled is not a clear? From several descriptions, the main idea of a calzone is that it's a _stuffed_ pizza, a pizza that is filled in the way you could fill a stocking. Your statement that _nobody_ can relate a calzone to a trouser leg or stocking is a clear overstatement.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia Your reference (which I posted in a comment earlier) clearly states that the pizza is named after a word that means trouser leg or stocking. _That word_ originally derived from a word meaning shoe, but the pizza is not named after  a shoe. That claim is similar to claiming the _sandwich_ somehow means _sandy beach_: it does not.

Comment: The sandwich reference doesn't make sense because sand doesn't figure anywhere in the etymological history of sandwich. Nevertheless, the question has been answered so no point in furthering this discussion. Thanks.

Comment: [*calzone*](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/calzone) is a "trouser leg" and its plural form [calzoni](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/calzoni) is another word for *pantaloni*, which is how the Americans got their word *pants* which in BrEng is normally called  *trousers* :) You can also *fill* the leg of your trousers, calzone, is a pizza just folded over itself. It is like a glorified wrap.

Comment: @Amit Yes, ‘sand’ figures in the etymological history of _sandwich_ just as much as ‘shoe’ figures in the etymological history of _calzone_. The name Sandwich, after which the food was named, comes from OE _sandwicæ_ ‘sand beach/harbour/trade post’. Claiming that _calzone_ means ‘shoe’ makes no more sense than claiming that _sandwich_ means ‘sandy beach’—in fact, it makes **less** sense, since the word _calzone_ has **never** meant ‘shoe’ in any stage of any language whatsoever.

Comment: @Mari-LouA +1 for the witch story. :)

Comment: Another interesting tidbit, and my main reason for looking this up, is that [*calzones*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6svViQS) is one of the words for “underwear” in Spanish. Figure that one out!

Comment: Actually, it comes from the zone in Italy where a lot of Californians have taken up residence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origin of the term 'calzone' meaning 'pizza calzone' is not clear. Actually calzone is the augmentative form of the term '[calza](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/Calza)' which means *stocking*. The idea is that  of a 'Christmas   stocking'  filled with food, a popular idea in the south of Italy.

As Mari Lou rightly pointed out, the stocking full of gifts we are referring to  comes from the [Epiphany Eve](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befana)  custom  which traditionally closes the Christmas period celebrations in Italy.

[image: Le calze della Befana]

Comment: The stocking is not really related to Father Christmas, but with the *Befana* an old ugly witch who flies on her broom (January 6th) and fills children's stockings with sweets, or lumps of coal and onions if the children have misbehaved during the year. Nowadays the lumps of coal are just black sugar candies in the form of coal/cokes. In WWII, many Italian families couldn't afford to buy  candy/sweets to fill the stockings, so they used tangerines and clementines instead.

Comment: Yes, I know...I mentioned 'Christmas' to make it more readily undestandable...the idea remains that of a stocking full of gifts.

Comment: Yes, but you're talking about *Italian* traditions, and *calzone* is an Italian expression not English one. And *food* is ambiguous, I might think that Sicilians fill their stockings with meat, pasta and cheese. It's not really *gifts* at least not traditionally, see my comment above. I would have answered this question myself, but what would I effectively add?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: in the U.S., there has been a tradition of putting an orange in Christmas stockings that goes back at least to the beginning of the 20th century [(see this web page)](http://davesgarden.com/guides/articles/view/1853/#b), which may have started because (except in Florida) they were more expensive and rarer than candy.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - as you know, the 'calza della Befana' has a long tradition in Italy, and  till a few decades ago to recieve one containing food and fruits was very common and appreciated. Nowadays they are just a commercial item usually filled with candies..'

Comment: There is a Mexican fast food that is like a taco or tostada, but served on a thick elongated tortilla. It is called a _huarache_, which is a type of sandal.